# O365 SharePoint auto login

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We have a SharePoint Domain and also Azure AD. We want to do auto login to our SharePoint online site when we are in network/domain (in office) through our windows credential.

Comment: Under `SharePoint Domain` you mean on-premise active directory, right? Right now, how your users are get authenticated with SharePoint online?

Comment: No it is Azure Active Directory (online). We are authenticating using our email address as username on O365 SharePoint site